# Why is beta minus particle denoted to have -1 proton number?

Tags: radiation

Why is beta minus particle denoted as having -1 as proton number?

Comment: If you have in mind an equation such as ${}_Z^AX^{Z^+}\to{}_{Z+1}^{A}X^{(Z+1)^+}+{}_{-1}^0e^{-}+{}_0^0\overline{\nu}_e$, the subscripted (superscripted) numbers denote charge (baryon number). But you really should edit the question to explain what you have in mind.

Comment: Can you link to a source which uses this convention? I can think of several problems with it off the top of my head.

Comment: @J.G. so z in the nuclear equation can represent charge (in case of electron) and proton number , in the case of element ?

Comment: My request for a link was for @Richie. I have seen this kind of notation, but it's easier to answer fully when there is an actual source which hopefully has its specific caveats stated clearly.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean baryon number, than the electron (beta-minus particle) has 0 baryon number

Answer (score 1):

The electron has a *charge number* of -1, a *spin number* of 1/2, and a *lepton number* of +1.

The proton has a *charge number* of +1, a *spin number* of 1/2, and a *baryon number* of +1.